# Can I copy/paste some of my answers to a blog?

Tags: discussion, legal, licensing

Some of my answers kind of look like blog articles (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/42165259/1225328 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/29797145/1225328).

The company I'm working for just starts a new tech blog. Am I *allowed* to copy/paste my own relevant answers to this blog (probably with slight modifications though)? I could add "Originally posted on Stack Overflow + link".

Comment: Hmm.  My gut says since it is your post you own the copyright so you can do what you want with it.  That said I do not know how edits should be handled.  If another user edits the post I'm not sure what the edited post is considered.

Comment: You can do whatever you want with your posts; as NathanOliver said, you hold the copyright on them.  That being said, I think it's a good idea to have a note on your blog to explain the connection.  There are a lot of scraper sites out there; you wouldn't want to be mistaken for one of them.

Comment: [Scientific infographic explaining the issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/123507/138112). There is no need for you to be mentioning Stack Overflow; the license you have granted SO is perpetual and irrevocable, but non-exclusive.

Comment: I mean if you wrote it and if you really wanted, you could just remove it from SO and then put it on your blog but that would make us all very sad.

Comment: @aug - Actually, users cannot do that. As Pekka explains in the comment above, the license granted to SO is irrevocable, and removing content posted by a user (in the scenario you point out) would violate that. This is why it is considered vandalism if users begin deleting all of their posts.

Comment: It is genuinely frightening that the content industry's scare tactics are so effective that someone would even *dream* to ask the question whether they are allowed to use *their own frigging content*!

Comment: @TravisJ thanks for posting that. I didn't know that although it makes sense. For people who want more info [see this meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266974/is-vandalism-of-own-deleted-posts-tolerated)

Comment: @JörgWMittag It's not really about being scared or not (*allowed* was probably not the right word), I just wanted to be fair with the Stack Overflow community and to have your points of view about this ;)

Comment: That is very noble of you, but the thing is: its yours. You can do whatever you want. I probably overreacted, and my reaction wasn't really directed at you, specifically. But, for example, back when we still allowed software licensing questions over at [softwareengineering.se], we would regularly get questions by people about what they were allowed to do with their own code once they released it as open source, and even worse, we would regularly get people who *answered* such questions with "don't use GPL, you will never be able to use your own code again". It seems to be a general "trend".

Comment: Note that there *are* legitimate concerns about the rights to creative works that you created for hire or as an employee, where indeed you may have given away some rights, depending on the exact nature of your contract / employment relationship and the jurisdiction you're in. But that is a completely different question, and nobody of the afore-mentioned answerers ever touched on that. They *either* genuinely believed what they were answering, namely that by open sourcing your code, you lose all rights, *or* they were a part of those scare tactics.

Comment: Well, to me, the question is not what you can do with your own work, but whether it is still *yours* after you post it on an SE site.  It is, but there are other sites and services where participation is conditioned on you waiving or even transferring your rights to anything you contribute.

Comment: Does your company plan to enforce a limiting license for content posted to that company blog? In that case you probably should clearly mark what you copied from your post here to keep the legal department of your company from erroneously going after stack overflow ;)

Comment: On my blog, I reproduced one of my old answers on InfoSec site because I deleted my profile there, so I want that post to remain mine.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**It’s your answer, and you are the only author?**
You may post it. No attribution required.

**It’s your answer, and other users edited it?**
If the edits were minor, you may post it without attribution. But if the edits were substantial, you may only post it if you attribute it according to (and license it under) *CC BY-SA 3.0*.

**It’s someone else’s answer?**
You may post it if you attribute it according to (and license it under) *CC BY-SA 3.0*.

Comment: Just as an aside; if it's your answer, and another user edited it, you can still post the *unedited version* of the answer without attribution. Their contribution, providing it wasn't minor grammar or whatnot, would be the part that requires attribution if it were substantial (as you note).

Comment: This is the first answer that covers the fact that not all SO answers are sole authorship in the current form.  This is an important point.  +1

Answer (score 70):

Since you are presumably the owner of that content, there is no need to mention SO, or that you also posted it there.  Such a citation would only be necessary for someone other than the owner.

If you *weren't* the owner of the content you provided to SO in the first place then *you shouldn't have posted it to SO to begin with*.  SO requires that user contributions be made by the owner of the content.  If you aren't the owner, and/or don't have the right to apply the CC-Wiki licence that SE applies to all user contributed content, then you would have violated SE's terms of service by posting it to so.

Comment: "*SO requires that user contributions be made by the owner of the content*" - really? I thought using appropriately licensed content would suffice.

Comment: It can, but you should include the same citations here as you would on a blog.

Comment: "Such a citation would only be necessary for someone other than the owner." - While this is *legally* the case, ethically speaking self-plagiarism is a thing.  It's considered good manners (at a minimum) to indicate when something has been posted elsewhere.

Comment: @Kevin There are certain contexts where citing yourself is important. For example, if you're writing a paper for a class, or a published academic journal, and you include a section of a work previously written by you, that would be something you would need to site, given the standards for plagiarism in that context.  If you're writing an informal personal blog, there really isn't an expectation of you citing yourself.  You certainly can if you want, but it's not really a reasonable expectation.

Comment: While _you_ know you didn't steal it, other people won't. I would include attribution and a link back to the original content on SO, if only so that people don't report the company blog as a SCRAPER.

Comment: @Stijn good call on swapping the two paragraphs -- I've done that.

Comment: I thought that once you post an answer/question here, it immediately becomes the property of SO/SE (which is why it's difficult to have something removed, if without significant merit).

Comment: @cybermonkey - That is inaccurate. You give *your content* to Stack Overflow. *You own it*. They then license it. Part of your user agreement is that they do so. Their license says if someone else uses it, they must then attribute it.

Comment: If you give Stack Overflow someone else's content, then that content must abide by someone else's license agreement. Often citation is the majority of requirement, which is why it is plagiarism to post content from somewhere else without citing it... for  example, to a tag wiki, or to Documentation.

Comment: so when a person refers to a solution/quote from programming language documentation or similar, and he/she includes the relevant quote in the answer (with appropriate attribution), do you see that as an issue? There are a lot of answers here like that. I think claim that user contributions are only made by the owner of the content is too strict - it should be ok if it's allowed by the original source/owner.

Comment: @eis How is that at all related to the topic under discussion?

Comment: "SO requires that user contributions be made by the owner of the content" - no, it doesn't.

Comment: @eis You can post your own original content that contains an appropriately cited quote.  That's still your own original work.

Answer (score 22):

*I saw none of the answers referenced the relevant legal texts yet, so I decided to write my own.*

## Yes.

Firstly, you would be allowed to copy the answers to your blog even if they *weren't* yours.

As the [Terms of Service](https://stackexchange.com/legal#3SubscriberContent) state:

> In the event that You post or otherwise use Subscriber Content outside of the Network or Services, with the exception of content entirely created by You, You agree that You will follow the attribution rules of the Creative Commons Attribution Share Alike license as follows:
>
> 1. You will ensure that any such use of Subscriber Content visually displays or otherwise indicates the source of the Subscriber Content as coming from the Stack Exchange Network. This requirement is satisfied with a discreet text blurb, or some other unobtrusive but clear visual indication.
> 2. You will ensure that any such Internet use of Subscriber Content includes a hyperlink directly to the original question on the source site on the Network (e.g., http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12345)
> 3. You will ensure that any such use of Subscriber Content visually display or otherwise clearly indicate the author names for every question and answer so used.
> 4. You will ensure that any such Internet use of Subscriber Content Hyperlink each author name directly back to his or her user profile page on the source site on the Network (e.g., http://stackoverflow.com/users/12345/username), directly to the Stack Exchange domain, in standard HTML (i.e. not through a Tinyurl or other such indirect hyperlink, form of obfuscation or redirection), without any “nofollow” command or any other such means of avoiding detection by search engines, and visible even with JavaScript disabled.
>      <sub>List changed from *a/b/c/d* to *1/2/3/4* because SE doesn't support the former</sub>

However, in your case you don't even need to follow these rules because, as the cited above, “content entirely created by You” is exempt from them.

Furthermore, although you have granted Stack Exchange a *license* to your contributions by accepting their ToS, you still retain ownership of the copyright and all neighboring rights to your creation. Also, although you did grant SE a license, ***nowhere*** do the Terms state that you've granted them an *exclusive* license.

Rather the opposite, in fact. That is because, [according](https://stackexchange.com/legal#3SubscriberContent) to those same Terms of Service, not only Stack Exchange users *but also Stack Exchange itself* is granted the right to use your contributions according to the terms of the *Creative Commons Attribution Share Alike license* (CC-BY-SA), which explicitly [states](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/legalcode):

> Subject to the terms and conditions of this License, Licensor hereby grants You a worldwide, royalty-free, **non-exclusive**, perpetual (for the duration of the applicable copyright) license…

The ToS section [linked](https://stackexchange.com/legal#3SubscriberContent) above also specifies a license that only applies to you and Stack Exchange, and which does not contain the same restrictions (e.g. "Share Alike") that apply to the CC license. This license does not claim exclusivity, either.

### That said,

it would nonetheless be wise to indicate that these are *your* answers which you've re-used from Stack Overflow; otherwise, you'll likely have to deal with angry blog commenters thinking you've taken other people's answers without their permission. Also, be warned that Google [does not like](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66359) certain kinds of duplicate content.

Comment: This also addresses @NathanOliver's comment "If another user edits the post I'm not sure what the edited post is considered." since in that case it wouldn't be "... content *entirely* created by You", so it's usage outside the Network would require attribution.

Answer (score 13):

I think Servy's analysis here is excellent with regards to content ownership and licensing.

One aspect to consider though, is that including a link to Stack Overflow only serves to give you more visibility. In my opinion that would be beneficial as well. I suppose if you didn't want the company to know you had a Stack Overflow account that would be different, but then again they are going to figure it out if you are posting near verbatim content from the same user all over the place. In the end, including a link would just be best; it would be the most honest and forthright way of doing this.

Also, keep in mind Stack Overflow is one of the most benevolent web based companies out there. They aren't going to go all ham on you for posting your own answers to your own personal blog.

Answer (score 2):

One thing I haven't seen covered here explicitly in an answer.

If you created the content *and no other person edited it*, then it's *entirely created by You* (per the legal terms) and you can do whatever you want with it with/without attribution.

Once someone edits, though, you can no longer do so, unless you make sure to only include the original work (before edits).  Edited posts are not created solely by anyone and so must be attributed.

Comment: I think this is already covered - at least by unor's answer.