# Can/should I copy my answers between SO/SE sites?

Tags: discussion, questions, duplicate-questions, duplicate-answers

Should I copy my own answers to duplicate/similar questions between different Stack Exchange sites?

I've encountered the following situation today when a user asked a [question](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/19459/calculation-of-jmp-address-through-subtraction) on the reverse engineering stack exchange site (where I'm an active user). It was indeed a good question and I spent a while writing a long detailed [answer](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/19467/2147).

When I was done I went about searching for additional materials and references as I often do, only this time I encountered an older, very similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546141/jmp-to-absolute-address-op-codes) on Stack Overflow. I honestly believe my answer will be beneficial for anyone seeing the Stack Overflow question as well, and therefore commented on the SO question and linked to the newer reverse engineering Stack Exchange site question I answered.

Is commenting appropriate? What was I supposed to do? Should I double-post my answer? Perhaps move it to Stack Overflow?

This is somewhat related to other meta questions, but they don't quite address this situation.

1. *[How do I handle duplicates when they are asked on other SE sites?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262292/how-do-i-handle-duplicates-when-they-are-asked-on-other-se-sites)*
2. *[Can I copy/paste some of my answers to a blog?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345404/can-i-copy-paste-some-of-my-answers-to-a-blog)*
3. *[Correct response to copied answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291113/correct-response-to-copied-answers)*

Comment: The real question is why do you search for additional references *after* answering?

Comment: @TGrif Maybe a better phrasing could be searching for additional information. Goal is to enrich the answer, of course. Some of the answered information, though, I know (because I have domain knowledge). I often go over my answer and reference other resources that will either support my knowledge and/or elaborate on it if a user is interested.

Comment: Of course. This is great. I mean you could have found the dupe before answering and have the appropriate reaction to that. If the question is relevant on reverseengineering.stackexchange, you should probably flag it on so as off topic.

Comment: Nowadays SO has a bunch of reverse engineering related or even centric questions. As far as I understand it, is it not the common practice to flag them as off topic (and there's no easy way for non-moderators to have it moved, as far as I'm aware). I guess I'd answer the first copy I'd encounter, and link the other one. I can see someone arguing that questions about hooking implementations or techniques are on topic on both sites.

Comment: Just post a link to the cross-site duplicate in the comments.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## No.  Copying/pasting the answer across sites fragments information.

If you believe your answer on SO to be a good *supplement* to another one of your answers on Engineering.SE, then you can leave that as a small part of your answer.  It should definitely not be the *crux* of your answer, but it can be used as something that can be referenced later.